# saving html table data into database

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have an html table called newTable, I want to save data from this table into MySQL tables. 
The issue I have is rows are inserted into newTable using jqueryselectors and individual row-column combination doesnt have a unique id/name (its a dynamic table which is populated at runtime)
Here how the data gets inserted into this table

```
var ntr='',//to store html for new table row
         rows=[],//to collect new rows
        $tbl=$("#table_rolecart tbody"),//original table
        l=$("tr", $tbl).length;//length of rows in original table's tbody section
        var row, brow, drow, trclass;
      for(var i=0;i<l;){
         row=$("tr:eq("+i+")", $tbl);//row with item name 
         brow=row.next("tr");//row with business justification textbox
         drow=brow.next("tr");//row with date textboxes

         ntr= '<tr><td>'+$("td:nth-child(2)",row).text()+'</td><td>'  //add item name
                +$("td:nth-child(3)",row).text()+'</td><td>'//add description
                +$(brow).find("input#ar_businessjust").val()+'</td><td>' //add business just.
                +$(drow).find("input#ar_startdate").val()+'</td><td>'//start date
                +$(drow).find("input#ar_enddate").val()+'</td></tr>';//end date
                rows.push(ntr);
     i+=4; //we have traversed 3 rows and one empty row, next item should be current + 4
        }
        $("#newTable tbody").append(rows.join(''));
```

So its basically a summary data populated from cart table. Currently the fields ar_businessjust,ar_startdate, ar_enddate are common fields with same id to all items in the cart
Even if I have a form surrounding it and do a form_id.serialize() to pass the parameters using jquery.ajax() call nothing is caught in it currently

Comment: its basically scanning 3 rows of rolecart table and appending them into a single row in summarycart table because each item in the cart occupies multiple rows (3 rows data + 1 spacer row = 4)

Comment: Comments like that belong in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

Not to start off in a negative manner, but using the same ID for several elements is not the way to go. Changing it to classes instead is a better bet.

However, when it comes to serialized forms, http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ (Is this what you're using?), says that only "successful controls" are serialized. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2 tells us that you need a name attribute.

My suggestion: change the IDs that is used several times to classes, and update your selectors for this. Add name attributes, and see if that helps.

However, I'm assuming here that you are in control of the code that prints the cart table as well.

Comment: For now I just created hidden variables next to td contents and those get passed when form is serialised, solved my problem though not the smoothest way..